# cannot change the id and text of the link using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following link in my view:

```
<a href="#" id="delete">Delete Data</a>
```

when I click on it, the data can be deleted successfully but I want to change the id and text of that link as well. Could you please check what is wrong with my code below.

```
$("#delete").click(function() {

    var self = this;

    //delete the data
    $(self).attr('id', 'restore');
    $(self).attr('text', 'Restore Data');
}
```

Comment: text is not an attribute. USe $(self).text("restore");

Comment: I'm assuming after changing the id you want a different handler to get called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .text() instead of attr to change text

```
$(self).text("newtext")
```

.attr('id') should work

```
 $(self).attr('id','restore')
```

but this will not remove the click event if you want the anchor to use another event after the id is changed unbind() the click or use event-delegation like this

```
$(staticParentElement).on('click','#delete',function(){
/*code*/
});

$(staticParentElement).on('click','#restore',function(){
/*code*/
});
```

Comment: Anton, after changing the id, I click on inspect element and see that id is changed, but when I click on the link, it still behaves like the id is 'delete'. When I view page source, I can see that id is still 'delete'. Perhaps I should remove that link and add a new link with new id instead of changing the id only?

Comment: @EducateYourself That's why you should use event-delegation like i showed $(staticParentElement).on('click'.....

Comment: Thanks Anton, now it works. The only problem is that when I click delete data, then browse within the site and then come back to that page with 'delete-restore' view, it suggest me to 'delete data' even though it should be 'restore data' as I already clicked 'delete data' previous time. Could you help my to bypass this problem as well?

Comment: @EducateYourself I'm not entierly sure what you mean but if i understand correctly you are looking for saving it as a cookie, or localStorage. You should probably ask a new question on stackoverflow for that.

Answer (score 2):

Try, small change

```
$(self).text('Restore Data');
```

id should change normally.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$("#delete").click(function() {

  var that = this;

  //delete the data

  $(that).attr('id', 'restore');
  $(that).text('Restore Data');

  });
```

Code check [here](http://jsbin.com/yabisi/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Text is not attribute So use variable if you want to use TEXT many times

```
var txt='Restore Data'
$(self).text(txt);
```